# how can I tell vimdiff to ignore whitespace?

Tags: vim, diff, whitespace

I made a number of changes in a file I'm working on, including indentation changes.  I'm using `vimdiff` to compare the file to the original version, and I don't want to see these changes, since they're basically cosmetic.

How can I tell `vimdiff` to ignore whitespace during the comparison?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

set diffopt+=iwhite
from [vim wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ignore_white_space_in_vimdiff)

Comment: Though that doesn't make it ignore *all* whitespace; see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1265410/834176).